# How to improve code folding in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want some automatic code folding for `if()`,`try()` etc.

It should be some code editor feature (like one in VS for methods, etc).

If I have this:

```
-        public frmMain()
|        {
|           InitializeComponent();
|           if (true)
|           {
|                try ()
|                {
|                }
|                catch()
|                {
|                }
|            }
|        }
```

I want to get this:

```
-        public frmMain()
|        {
|           InitializeComponent();
-           if (true)
|           {
-                try ()
|                {
|                }
-                catch()
|                {
|                }
|            }
|        }
```

Even Notepad++ can do this!

Comment: huh???Both are the same...do you mean regions?

Comment: He wants code-folding widgets for any code block: if, try, catch, and presumably the other keywords like while, finally, et al.

Comment: They aren't the same.. The bar on the left is the difference.

Answer (score 15):

For C#;

1. Tools, Options, Text Editor
2. Expand C/C++
3. Advanced
4. Outlining -> Turn on ***Enter outlining mode when files open***

For C/C++;

1. Tools, Options, Text Editor
2. Expand C/C++
3. Formatting
4. Outlining -> Turn on ***Enable Outlining*** & ***Outline Statement Blocks***

Tested in VS2010

Comment: Awesome, I thought VS2010 was just lacking proper code folding like C#. Nice to see it's supported by default, I just needed to look deeper into my settings.

Answer (score 5):

I don't normally post things I've not personally used, but in this case, I was able to find an add-in that Jay Flowers wrote which seems to do exactly what you want. Currently, it can be located and downloaded [here](http://jayflowers.com/WordPress/?p=134), with source in case you wanted to add more features or change its functionality.

Comment: Thanks, really good feature!
But not automated ((
Anyway, very helpful and convinient!

Comment: No, I don't believe it's automated. :( Like I said, I just sort of found it. :) I believe there are others out there -- maybe some of the big name paid VS add-ins have something similar.